# What's a Winnie?

Tags: meaning

In the song [The Virginia Company](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/pocahontas/thevirginiacompany.htm) at the beggining of the film *Pocahontas*, in the last verse a *Winnie* is mentioned in the line: *With a nugget for my winnie and another one for me*.

What is a *Winnie*?

Answer (score 2):

I presume it just refers to the man's wife [**Winifred**](http://www.behindthename.com/name/winifred) (short form Winnie) and that name was used in the song simply because it rhymes with Virginie in the previous verse.

P.S. You incorrectly transcribed it as, "With a nugget for my winnie".  In fact, by following the link you gave, I see that the original has, "With a nugget for my Winnie" and that use of a capital letter clearly indicates it is someone's name.

Comment: I figured that the fact that multiple people were singing it and that it had _my_ before it, meant that it had some sort of meaning. Perhaps wife or mother or something like that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: However, if you read the next line, you will see that the person singing is 'me' and therefore singular, i.e.  "With a nugget for my Winnie, And another one for *me*".  Note that it is common to refer to a spouse as "my John" or "my Mary" and so on.